# Send data between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have two models: `Activity` and `Comment`. `Comment` `belongs_to :activity` and `Activity` `has_many :comments`. For building activities, I've followed this [Railscast (Activity feed from scratch)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch)

So, I'm using `activity_presenter.rb`

```
class ActivityPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  attr_reader :activity

  def initialize(activity, view)
    super(view)
    @activity = activity
  end

  def render_activity
    div_for activity do
      link_to((gravatar_for activity.user, {size: 20}) + activity.user.name, activity.user) + ' ' + render_partial
    end
  end

  def render_partial
    locals = {activity: activity, presenter: self}
    locals[activity.trackable_type.underscore.to_sym] = activity.trackable
    render partial_path, locals
  end

  def partial_path
    partial_paths.detect do |path|
      lookup_context.template_exists? path, nil, true
    end || raise("No partial found for activity in #{partial_paths}")
  end

  def partial_paths
    [
        "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}",
        "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}",
        "activities/activity"
    ]
  end
end
```

which renders `_activities_feed.rb` partial with `@activities.each do |activity|` condition.

In this partial I have 3 blocks:

- `activity` with `form for activity` for updating purposes
- `activity.comments` block with `each do |comment|`
- `activity.comments.new` (form)

And this is a problem. I need to render `Activity.comments` and form for creating a new comment from `comments` controller, because I have 2 forms in one view and 2 `submit` buttons, which call 2 `update` or `create` actions. And, of course, I need it for making app logic better.

But I can't send `activity` from `@activities.each do |activity|`, which I use everywhere in this partial to `comments_controller`.

I've tried to add `@activity = Activity.find(params[:id])`, `@comment = Activity.comments.new(params[:activity_id])`, `@comments = Activity.comments.all` to `activities` and `comments` controllers, and also changed `activity` to `@activity` and `activity.comments.new` to `@comment`. But it doesn't help. I think, that I don't understand the basic logic of interaction between controllers, but can't find my mistakes.

So, my `activities_controller`'s `index` action is:

```
@activities = Activity.order('updated_at DESC')
```

And in `comments_controller` I only have `create` and `destroy` actions, which work ok.

Thanks for any help!

UPD:

This is my `_activities_feed.rb` structure:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= form_for activity, remote: true do |a| %>
    <%= ActivityPresenter.new(activity, self).render_activity %>
    .
    .         
    .
    <%= link_to ... class: 'add_comment', remote: true %> # Shows activity.new.comment form
    <%= link_to ... 'Edit' ... %> # edit activity link
    <%= a.submit 'Update' %> # first submit button for submitting activity changes
    .
    .
    .
    <% activity.comments.each do |comment| %> # activity.comments block
       <%= comment.text %>
       <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
    <% end %>
    .
    .
    .
    <%= form_for activity.comments.new, remote: true do |f| %> # form for adding comment
       <%= f.text_area :text, 'rows' => '2', class: 'comment_text' %>
       <%= f.button 'Cancel', class: 'btn comment_cancel', type: 'button' %>
       <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary', controller: 'comments' %> # second submit button
       <%= f.hidden_field :activity_id, value: activity.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of dumping all details, I prefer the question to be a bit more abstract and concentrate. I feel hard to grasp what is the real problem with too much your detailed domain logics.

Comment: I'd prefer if you could show us the `form` that you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, forget about the form. Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with nested forms. So, when I submitted form for new comment, it also submitted the parent form for updating activity.